# How a chaining interface like Rails ActiveRecord is built?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm intrigued. How `User.where(name: 'Foo').where(age: 20)` works with only one database call?

Does the method `where` know if it is the last of the chain and change its behavior? And if so, how that can be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It returns `self` after each time it adds the query to its internal query builder.

`where` doesn't necessarily know where it's at; ActiveRecord waits for itself to be enumerated on before even querying the database. Example:

```
users = User.where(active: true)
users.loaded? # false 
users.each { }
users.loaded? # true
```

`each`, `map`, `first`, `last`, etc. all will trigger the query to be loaded.

Here's an example of a super-naive query builder:

```
class FakeRecord
  include Enumerable
  def self.all_args
    @all_args ||= []
  end

  def self.where(*args)
    all_args << args 
    self
  end

  def self.each
    puts "Executing sql #{all_args.join(", ")}"
    yield [1, 2, 3]
  end
end

FakeRecord.where(potato: true).where(dinosaur: false).each do |thing|
  puts thing
end
```